# Unable to Create SQL Server DataStore in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I am new to GeoServer, I wanna access my MSSQL server Database in GeoServer so that I would be able to share my Spatial Data directly from SQL Server. But Whenever I try to create the DataStore in GeoServer

It generates an error

Here are the parameters  I am giving to create the datastore and error is also listed in picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EjZX.png).

[GeoServer Screen Shot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EjZX.png) [GeoServer Screen Shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmyx7.png)[GeoServer Screen Shot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSYNe.png)[GeoServer Screen Shot 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFQiP.png)
the port number in [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSYNe.png) is same as I found in [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFQiP.png)

Kindly let me know whats wrong with this procedure...

Anxiously waiting for good response from your side

Comment: I solved the above mystery by changing the 'hostname' as 'localhost' instead of the SQL Instance 'SQLEXPRESS'.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above mystery by changing the 'hostname' as 'localhost' instead of my current SQL Instance 'SQLEXPRESS'.